# Errors in removing duplicate sequences fasta file - problem in the header

Tags: python, duplicates, biopython, fasta

I am trying to combine some protein sequences in fasta format and then remove duplicates. I found this code by searching and it works well enough but I ran into an issue that I couldn't understand. Here is the example sequence which is causing the error:

```
>someseq1
MKYFPLFPTLVFAARVVAFPAYASLAGLSQQELDAIIPTLEAREPGLPPGPLENSSAKLV
>firstseq with 5 mutations:
MKYFPLFPTLVFAARVVAFPAYASLAGLSQQELDAIIPTLEAREPGLPPGPLENSSAKLV
>secondseq with 9 mutations:
MKYFPLFPTLVYAVGVVAFPDYASLAGLSQQELDAIIPTLEAREPGLPPGPLENSSAKLV
>thirdseq
MISQSFVSLTVLLLGLVNLSPAFAFPQYGSLAGLSARDLNVLIPRLNEVDPPTPPGPLAYNGTKLVHDDA
>thirdone – in claim
MISTSKHLFVLLPLFLVSHLSLVLGFPAYASLGGLTERQVEEYTSKLPIVFPPPPPEPIKDPWLKLVNDR
```

The original file and sequences are long so I shortened it for ease.

I found this code on the forum which works fine and writes a new file without duplicates:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import time

start = time.time()

seen = []
records = []

for record in SeqIO.parse("Prob2.fa", "fasta"):
    if str(record.seq) not in seen:
        seen.append(str(record.seq))
        records.append(record)


#writing to a fasta file
SeqIO.write(records, "Checked.fa", "fasta")
end = time.time()

print(f"Run time is {(end- start)/60}")
```

Now, the Python interpreter is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arif\Desktop\DuplicateSequenceFinder\DuplicateFinder.py", line 10, in <module>
    for record in SeqIO.parse("Prob2.fa", "fasta"):
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\Interfaces.py", line 72, in __next__
    return next(self.records)
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\FastaIO.py", line 238, in iterate
    for title, sequence in SimpleFastaParser(handle):
  File "C:\Users\Arif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\FastaIO.py", line 50, in SimpleFastaParser
    for line in handle:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 449: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I found the problem is in the header with "-" character written as "- in claim" (the third sequence in list). If I remove that it works fine, but there are other "-" mentioned in other sequence headers as well. I found it by removing half of the sequences and checking if it still gives an error. Now, if I delete this "-" and type a new "-", it works fine. So I am just trying to understand what is the real problem here. So I can write in the correct input format in the future.

I originally wrote these sequences in Word, and later edit them in Notepad++ and save it as ".fa" file.

Secondly, I want to find out how many duplicates were found and mention the record IDs/headers. So if someone can help me with what lines of codes I should insert, I will be very grateful.

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue. Not sure why the data is being decoded with the GBK decoder. This is a chinese adaptation. You should try with the appropriate one for the data you have.
I would advise to open the file yourself with the codec appropriate to your data and handle it to the `parse` method, so it already have the decoded data and does not try to use the GBK one.

Comment: I would also advice you to use a set instead of a list for the sequence lookups, for performance reasons, specially when the number of different records grow to sensible amounts.

Comment: ok. the first comment went way above my current head. I have got a long way to learn.

Comment: What does: "for line in open(filename):
    pint(line) " gives you for your file ??? Filename is your file

Comment: Try using:  with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: and then feed it to SeqIO.parse as a StringIO(f.read) --> SeqIO.parse(StringIO(f.read)) see https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py line 585

Comment: @pippo1980. I just checked to read the lines as you asked. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arif\Desktop\Python Script Testing\DuplicateSequenceFinder\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    for line in open ('Prob2.fa'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 449: illegal multibyte sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my attempt , cannot reproduce your error.
But using your same input:

```
>someseq1
MKYFPLFPTLVFAARVVAFPAYASLAGLSQQELDAIIPTLEAREPGLPPGPLENSSAKLV
>firstseq with 5 mutations:
MKYFPLFPTLVFAARVVAFPAYASLAGLSQQELDAIIPTLEAREPGLPPGPLENSSAKLV
>secondseq with 9 mutations:
MKYFPLFPTLVYAVGVVAFPDYASLAGLSQQELDAIIPTLEAREPGLPPGPLENSSAKLV
>thirdseq
MISQSFVSLTVLLLGLVNLSPAFAFPQYGSLAGLSARDLNVLIPRLNEVDPPTPPGPLAYNGTKLVHDDA
>thirdone - in claim
MISTSKHLFVLLPLFLVSHLSLVLGFPAYASLGGLTERQVEEYTSKLPIVFPPPPPEPIKDPWLKLVNDR
```

**try with the following code:**

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import time

start = time.time()

seen = []
records = []

filename = 'Prob2.fa'

with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
    for record in SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta"):
        if str(record.seq) not in seen:
            seen.append(str(record.seq))
            records.append(record)


#writing to a fasta file
SeqIO.write(records, "Checked.fa", "fasta")
end = time.time()

print(f"Run time is {(end- start)/60}")
```

let us know if it is working.

I can reproduce your error using in my code:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='gbk') as f:
```

adding the char : `丆` to one of your headers

but I dont get the error anymore if I delete the `丆` from the fasta header

As Poshi pointed out:

> This looks like an encoding issue. Not sure why the data is being decoded with the GBK decoder.

SEE [https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/**init**.py#L559](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py#L559) for explanation about :

how to feed data to `SEqIO.parse(..` :

> Arguments:
> - handle   - handle to the file, or the filename as a string

> .......

> If you have a string 'data' containing the file contents, you must
> first turn this into a handle in order to parse it:

As Poshi said, it should not be a *Biopython*  issue, try with just:

```
filename = 'Prob2.fa'

with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f: #or encoding='gbk' 
    
    print(f.read())
```

on the same file and see if you get same error

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your time. This works and I didn't get any error.